# groovy + how to match line from parameter

Tags: java, groovy

I run some external command from my groovy script

I print from my groovy script the external command results by this:

```
 println "stdout: ${proc.in.text}"   )
```

.

my full groovy script

```
  path='C:/Program Files/Systems/VPN/vpnclient.exe'


  NAME = "JGSVGVGBGVG"
  PASS = "JHBYGTGFBV"
  USER = "HBTFTNI"


  def command = """ $path connect user $USER pwd $PASS "$NAME"  """
  def proc = command.execute()                 

  proc.waitFor()                               

 // Obtain status and output
 println "return code: ${ proc.exitValue()}"
 println "stderr: ${proc.err.text}"
 println "stdout: ${proc.in.text}"
```

groovy script print part the following output:

```
 .
 .
 .
 Authenticating user.
 Negotiating security policies.
 Securing communication channel.
 Your VPN connection is secure.
```

Until now everything is OK

Now I want to match the line “**Your VPN connection is secure**” from results

So I create the following code in groovy and add this code to my original groovy script: ( in order to match the line ) ,

```
  line= 'Your VPN connection is secure.'
  def matcher = ${proc.in.text}.matcher(line)
  def count = matcher.getCount()
  println "Matches = ${count}"
```

I get “Exception”  ,   I am very new in groovy I not understand what wrong in my code
And what need to fix in order to match the line - **Your VPN connection is secure**

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a GString dollar syntax which should be between double quotes, but is not needed in this case. You can just use the *string matcher operator*, `=~`.

I wrote a small mock (with the `proc=[in:[text:`) just to make the assertion work, it is not needed in your script:

```
proc=[in:[text:
  '''
    Authenticating user.
    Negotiating security policies.
    Securing communication channel.
    Your VPN connection is secure.
'''
]]
line= 'Your VPN connection is secure.'
def matcher = proc.in.text =~ line
def count = matcher.getCount()
assert count == 1
```

---

**Update:** you must not use the `proc.in.text` twice, you need to store its results in a variable and then reread the variable:

```
path='C:/Program Files/Systems/VPN/vpnclient.exe'

NAME = "JGSVGVGBGVG"
PASS = "JHBYGTGFBV"
USER = "HBTFTNI"

def command = """ $path connect user $USER pwd $PASS "$NAME"  """
def proc = command.execute()                 

proc.waitFor()                               

def output = proc.in.text

// Obtain status and output
println "return code: ${ proc.exitValue()}"
println "stderr: ${proc.err.text}"
println "stdout: ${output}" 

def matcher = (output =~ 'Your VPN connection is secure.')
def count = matcher.count
```

Comment: I get - " Exception thrown

java.io.IOException: Stream closed " , what could be the problem , I want to print 1 if its match or print 0 if we not match the line

Comment: what is the diff beetween your example to my code ? ,

Comment: Seems like you have already read from the stream, you can't use `proc.in.text` multiple times. Save it to a variable and use the variable

Comment: Please can you give example or maybe add this to you code example ( I am very new in groovy )

Comment: You need to write `def output = proc.in.text` and start using only `output` from now on, when you want to match the process output. If you write `proc.in.text` again, it will throw the same error. If this doesn't help, you will need to post your full code

Comment: now I use the "output" in place matcher in my code and it dosent help , please see my full code ( update )